# Mathematica running very slowly with just 4 integrals. Memoization?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, memoization

While playing with Fourier Integrals, I've noticed my computations taking an excessively long time to calculate. I just have two sets of a Piecewise function, two functions and two integrals. I wouldn't think Mathematica would need to take so long to compute these. What, in particular, is slowly my computations down so much? How can I improve computation time? Will using some combination of memoization help ( :=, for which I don't quite understand)?

Decreasing the Limit on the integrals helps slightly, but not as much as I'd think.

My code is the following:

```
    MM = 50;
    qf = 10;

    (*First Set*)
    f[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 0.5}, {0, t > 0.5}}];
    A[w_] = qf Sin[w/2]/(Pi w);
    B[w_] = qf (1 - Cos[w/2])/(Pi w);
    f[x_] = Integrate[A[w] Cos[w x], {x, 0, MM}];
    g[x_] = Integrate[B[w] Sin[w x], {x, 0, MM}];
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
    Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
    Plot[f[x] + g[x], {x, 0, 1}]

    (*Second Set*)
    ff[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 0.5}, {0, t > 0.5}}];
    AA[w_] = qf (Sin[w] - Sin[w/2])/(Pi w);
    BB[w_] = -qf (Cos[w] - Cos[w/2])/(Pi w);
    ff[x_] = Integrate[AA[w] Cos[w x], {x, 0, MM}];
    gg[x_] = Integrate[BB[w] Sin[w x], {x, 0, MM}];
    Plot[ff[x], {x, 0, 1}]
    Plot[gg[x], {x, 0, 1}]
    Plot[ff[x] + gg[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Ran within several seconds for me. The `Plot`s came out empty though. Also, you might have better luck [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Without fixing your code so that it can be tested by others, this question is not replicatable and should be closed.

Comment: The result of evaluating a definite integral will not be a function of the integration variable.. (!)

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your code as shown:

1. You haven't defined `w` so e.g. `f[x_]` isn't fully evaluated
2. you define `f[t_]` then `f[x_]` which overwrites the first definition
3. You're misusing `Piecewise`. It should be something like `pw = Piecewise[{{Sin[x]/x, x < 0}, {1, x == 0}}, -x^2/100 + 1]`